Using Entity Framework, I want to link a parent to a child object based on a textfield on the child
I have an entity, Country that has a textfield called Text. (Autogenerated from XML structure)
I want to link the parent object PortalAddress to the Country so that when I load data from the XML document, using xml.Deserialize, the Country on the PostalAddress is set to an existing Country, if this Country already exists.
Example:
I have a:
<PostalAddress>
  <Country>Denmark</Country>
</PostalAddress>

But, there is already a Country with Denmark in the Database, with ID=1, so how do I now link this so that my newly added PostalAddress is added with link to the Country with ID=1
I have set up parent/child where PostalAddress as link to a single Country and a onetomany on the Country table to the PostalAddress table.
But if the XML contains multiple i.e. 3 PostalAddresses, with Denmark as Text I get 3 entities of Country in the database.
I've tried SO many things in the DbContext, but I simply cannot find a solution.
Hope it makes sence and that someone can help. Thanks
I've tried making all types of WithMany, HasOne.. on the context.
But nowhere do I find a posibility for saying country => country.Text  == postalAdress.Country.Text

You probably will not be able to automatically deserialize the XML into the right DB model automatically. Deserialize the XML into a temp model. Read all the countries from the DB into a dictionary. Manually convert the temp model into the DB model by using the dictionary. Since you have shown no code, it is difficult to give you an example code.

Yes I'm aware I did not show any code, problem is that I'm not allowed to at the moment :-)
But what you are saying is exactly what I've been thinking so far and working on.
But there are so many "magic" functions that I hoped someone new some way to do this.
Thanks though.
